# Python - how to get text to appear on same line when iterating?

Tags: python, terminal, screen, iteration

When I iterate over certain lines in Python, I'd like them to appear on the same line and overwrite the last line displayed rather than appear on a separate line. For example:

```
files = [ "pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg","pic3.jpg"]

for line in files:
  print "Current file is:", line
```

The current result is:

```
Current file is: pic1.jpg
Current file is: pic2.jpg
Current file is: pic3.jpg
```

Desired result is:

```
Current file is: pic3.jpg
```

..after the other 2 files have shown up after "Current file is:". In other words, instead of multiple lines, the results all fit on one line, with the current iteration overwriting the previous item.

How do I get this to work on Python for Windows (or Linux, for that matter?)

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to investigate [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

Comment: Thanks, chrisaycock. Does that work on Windows, too?

Comment: @Tensigh: Unfortunately, `curses` only works on Windows if you install a `libcurses` port, then either rebuild Python from source, or find a third-party replacement for the `curses` stdlib module. That can be reasonable if your goal is to release a packaged-up binary installer, but not so much if you want to write a script that can be run with reasonable dependencies.

Comment: @Tensigh: But if you're doing something simple enough, you may want to take a look at the `conio` functions in the stdlib `msvcrt` module for Windows, and `curses` for *nix, and write a little cross-platform wrapper that covers just the simple stuff you need in the appropriate way on each platform. (Or search PyPI, ActiveState, etc. to see if anyone else has already done that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\r` character to go back to the beginning of the current line, but using `sys.stdout.write` instead of the `print` function (or statement), because this will automatically add the `\r\n` characters at the end of the string.

Here's an example function to see how this works:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def print_same_line():
    for i in range(10):
        stdout.write("\rCounter: {0}.".format(i))
        sleep(1)
    stdout.write("\n")

print_same_line()
```

Based on your example:

```
for line in files:
    stdout.write("\rCurrent file is: " + line)
stdout.write("\n")
```

---

Here's a little trick to erase the previous printed line:

```
files = ["some_long_text_file.txt", "another_file.png", "short.jpg"]

previous = ""
for line in files:
    stdout.write("\r" + " " * len(previous) + "\r" + line)
    previous = line
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just make sure that if the lines aren't all the same length you pad it with extra spaces to overwrite leftover characters. Nothing looks tackier than "Current file is: pic9.jpgpg" because the last line was "pic111.jpg".

Comment: @abarnert You're right! But in this case, since the files are named `fileN.jpg`, then the current line will never be lower than the previous.

Comment: @cdonts, that worked great when iterating through lists. I'm having a problem with it reading lines from a file. Using your second example, I have Python reading lines from a file. As it reads each line, it creates a new line instead of redrawing the line.

Comment: @cdonts: As long as they're in natural-sorted order. I've had cases like this where I, e.g., read them from `os.listdir('.')`, or from a pipe from another program, and they came out in alphabetical order. Of course those real-life cases also have to deal with filenames that are too long to fit in a single line in the terminal (and it's always fun dealing with programs that don't handle that and end up spamming your scrollback buffer)… Anyway, your answer gives him the magic he was missing to start writing his program, and hopefully he can figure out any details that come up from there.

Comment: @cdonts: Yeah, that's another solution. I've done a quick&dirty version of the same thing in C, where I prefix each line with `"\r<79 spaces>\r"`. And it looks like it may be easier for a novice to understand, which makes it a win.

Comment: @abarnert I like that too!

Comment: @cdonts, that was awesome and it worked. I'm working with a lot of shift-jis characters so I had to modify "len(previous)" to "(len(previous)+4)" in order to get it work. Being double byte characters has thrown the whole thing off. Thanks for the mod!

Answer (score 2):

I usually do:

```
print "\r%d" % (x),
```

The comma at the end tells print to stay in the same line, and \r is re carriage return (no line feed). x would be a variable, in code like this:

```
for x in xrange(100):
    print "\r%5d" % (x),
```

**Edit:** @abarnert's comment

Comment: It's usually better to use a format width (or `rjust`, if you prefer) instead of adding spaces on the end. That way you can do things like restrict the string to 79 characters and pad it out to 79 without accidentally wrapping to the next line.

Comment: Good catch! How about now?

Comment: Well, you probably want `%-5d` to left-justify (and I made the exact same mistake with `rjust` rather than `ljust`…), since that seems to better fit the OP's desired output. (Also, you're missing an indent.) But otherwise, yeah, working solution with a nice explanation.

Comment: @bconstanzo - Thank you, that worked great. There are a couple of tweaks I need, but this worked pretty well! Currently I'm trying to figure out how to use the rjust method that abarnet suggested. I'm trying to add spaces to remove the "artifacts" but it's not working.

Comment: @Tensigh, rjust is a method of string objects that justifies the string to occupy at least N characters (fill with whitespace) [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) has some examples of `rjust`, `ljust` and `center` which might be useful.